# Index Match function with multiple criteria Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I tried to copy&paste data from one table to another and found the index match excel function very helpful. So one criteria is a number and the other is the date. 
I found a very good article about the function with multiple criteria but it doesn't work and i cant understand why.
https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/

I attached the file where i tried my luck. Maybe you can help me find my mistake.
https://ufile.io/3kau7

Comment: Please put the relevant data in the OP using edit.  many of us will not download files from the internet.  Also show the actual formula you have tried.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/FkBXn

Comment: =INDEX(F136:H140,MATCH(F144&G143,F136:F140&G135:H135,0))    I tried that as an array function

Answer (score 2):

No array formula needed:

```
=INDEX($A:$C,MATCH($A11,$A:$A,0),MATCH(B$10,1:1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah you are right, thanks! But why so complicated at the post of deskbright? Where is the difference? Why they use an array formula?

Comment: @P.Schmid That has to do with multiple criteria in two columns or two rows, not one row and one column.  If your data is like this Array formula are not needed.

Comment: Perfect example for `INDEX`ing a bi-dimensional array ;)

Comment: I just tried it on the original file i uploaded and i can't make it there -.-. Does excel care what kind of format the data is? Text or number? I don't understand why it doesn't work in the larger example file

Comment: It does matter, if one of the inputs is a date and the area it is searching is a text string that looks like a date then it will not find a match.

Comment: Seems like it has something to do with the data format. When i copy the number which i want to search from the original table in the new table, it works. Seems the format was different even excel said both was in "general".